# Observable list not updating from js Callback

Tags: dart, parse-platform

*I'm trying to update my template from within a `js.Callback`. When i do `cities.add("test")` from my `main()` it works fine and updates my template with the string, but doing the same within the callback the template is not updating. I'm trying to use the Javascript API from [Parse.com](http://parse.com). Login works and getting objects from querys as well. I just started out learning Dart, so maybe it's something very obvious i'm missing?*

Update: Problem solved by calling js.retain(Parse) and then dispatch() 
Working solution below.

*myDart.html* :

```html
<template iterate="city in cities"> {{city}} </template>
```

*myDart.dart* :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

var Parse = js.context.Parse;

List<String> cities = new List();

void main() {

  js.retain(Parse); //Solution to problem (1/2)

  Parse.initialize("id", "key");

  if(Parse.User.current() == null) {

    Parse.User.logIn("user", "password",
        js.map({
          "success": new js.Callback.once((user) => parseData()),
          "error": new js.Callback.once((user,error) => print(error.message))
        })
    );
  }
  else
    parseData();

  cities.add("hej");
}

void parseData() {

  //Get Cities
  var City = Parse.Object.extend("City");
  var query = new js.Proxy(Parse.Query, City);
  query.equalTo(js.map({"ACL" : Parse.User.current()}));

  query.find(
    js.map({
      "success": new js.Callback.once((array){  
        for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
          String cityName = array[i].get("name");
          cities.add(cityName);
          dispatch(); //Solution to problem (2/2)
        }
      }),
      "error": new js.Callback.once((object,error) => print(error.message))
    })    
  );
}
```

Comment: could you post your `getMyCity()` method? Could not reproduce this strange behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I updated the post with the full version of my dart file.

Comment: The query-method(named geyMyCity in my simplified post) is loaded from a js-file from Parse.com, i'm loading that script in the head of my html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be 2 problems with your code :

- you should call  [`watcher.dispatch()`](http://dart-lang.github.io/web-ui/docs/watcher.html#dispatch) after having updated your list through your callback.
- the top level variable `Parse` is a `js.Proxy` that is used in a callback. This proxy has to be retained (with `js.retain(Parse)`) to be used outside of the current eventloop otherwise you will get an error like *js ref has been invalidated*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cities = toObservable(new List())`? Also, it works just fine without it. That was my first idea, too, so I checked that.

Comment: I think `cities = toObservable(new List())` should work but it doesn't. Is it a bug ? It looks like.

Comment: Thank you so much! Retaining and then dispatching solved the problem.